# hibernate ogm Could not obtain JBoss Transactions transaction manager instance

Tags: java, mongodb, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-ogm

I'm trying to run hibernate ogm in standalone mode (not jee container).
my persistence.xml file is the following

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="primary" transaction-type="JTA">
        <!-- Use Hibernate OGM provider: configuration will be transparent -->
        <provider>org.hibernate.ogm.jpa.HibernateOgmPersistence</provider>
        <properties>
             <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.provider" value="infinispan"/>
              <property name="hibernate.ogm.mongodb.database" value="Heroku Read Only"/>
              <property name="hibernate.ogm.mongodb.host" value="host"/>
              <property name="hibernate.ogm.mongodb.port" value="99999"/>
              <property name="hibernate.ogm.mongodb.username" value="user"/>
              <property name="hibernate.ogm.mongodb.password" value="pass"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

in my main i added the following code

```
private static EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;
public static void main(String[] args){
       entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory( "primary" );
       EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
}
```

when I run my main I get the following exception

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.spi.JtaPlatformException:
>   Could not obtain JBoss Transactions transaction manager instance

here after all the log

```
janv. 06, 2017 5:04:13 PM org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper logPersistenceUnitInformation INFO: HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
        name: primary
        ...] janv. 06, 2017 5:04:13 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.1.Final} janv. 06, 2017 5:04:13 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit> INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found janv. 06, 2017 5:04:13 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist janv. 06, 2017 5:04:13 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit> INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final} janv. 06, 2017 5:04:15 PM org.hibernate.ogm.datastore.impl.DatastoreProviderInitiator initiateService INFO: OGM000016: NoSQL Datastore provider: org.hibernate.ogm.datastore.infinispan.impl.InfinispanDatastoreProvider janv. 06, 2017 5:04:15 PM org.hibernate.ogm.transaction.impl.OgmJtaPlatformInitiator initiateService INFO: OGM000075: JBoss Transaction Manager (com.arjuna.ats.jta.TransactionManager) detected on classpath. Using JBossStandAloneJtaPlatform as JTAPlatform implementation janv. 06, 2017 5:04:15 PM org.hibernate.ogm.dialect.impl.GridDialectInitiator$GridDialectInstantiator newInstance INFO: OGM000017: Grid Dialect: org.hibernate.ogm.datastore.infinispan.InfinispanDialect janv. 06, 2017 5:04:15 PM org.hibernate.ogm.dialect.impl.GridDialectInitiator$GridDialectInstantiator newInstance INFO: Grid dialect logs are disabled janv. 06, 2017 5:04:15 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init> INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.ogm.dialect.impl.OgmDialect janv. 06, 2017 5:04:15 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.LobCreatorBuilderImpl makeLobCreatorBuilder INFO: HHH000422: Disabling contextual LOB creation as connection was null janv. 06, 2017 5:04:15 PM org.hibernate.ogm.cfg.impl.Version <clinit> INFO: OGM000001: Hibernate OGM 5.0.0.CR1 Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.spi.JtaPlatformException: Could not obtain JBoss Transactions transaction manager instance
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.JBossStandAloneJtaPlatform.locateTransactionManager(JBossStandAloneJtaPlatform.java:35)
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.AbstractJtaPlatform.retrieveTransactionManager(AbstractJtaPlatform.java:87)
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.AbstractJtaPlatform.getTransactionManager(AbstractJtaPlatform.java:98)
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.TransactionManagerBasedSynchronizationStrategy.canRegisterSynchronization(TransactionManagerBasedSynchronizationStrategy.java:39)
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.AbstractJtaPlatform.canRegisterSynchronization(AbstractJtaPlatform.java:131)
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaTransactionCoordinatorImpl.pulse(JtaTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:141)
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaTransactionCoordinatorImpl.<init>(JtaTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:92)
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaTransactionCoordinatorBuilderImpl.buildTransactionCoordinator(JtaTransactionCoordinatorBuilderImpl.java:28)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.<init>(SessionImpl.java:273)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl$SessionBuilderImpl.openSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1322)
        at org.hibernate.ogm.hibernatecore.impl.OgmSessionBuilderDelegator.openSession(OgmSessionBuilderDelegator.java:39)
        at org.hibernate.ogm.hibernatecore.impl.OgmSessionBuilderDelegator.openSession(OgmSessionBuilderDelegator.java:25)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl.internalGetSession(EntityManagerImpl.java:133)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.postInit(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:174)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl.<init>(EntityManagerImpl.java:83)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.internalCreateEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:319)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:286)
        at org.hibernate.ogm.jpa.impl.OgmEntityManagerFactory.createEntityManager(OgmEntityManagerFactory.java:45)
        at com.energielibre.middleware.service.mongodatalayergeneric.Tester.main(Tester.java:26) Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.JBossStandAloneJtaPlatform.locateTransactionManager(JBossStandAloneJtaPlatform.java:32)
        ... 18 more Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: missing property file arjuna-properties.xml
        at com.arjuna.common.internal.util.propertyservice.BeanPopulator.getNamedInstance(BeanPopulator.java:81)
        at com.arjuna.common.internal.util.propertyservice.BeanPopulator.getDefaultInstance(BeanPopulator.java:49)
        at com.arjuna.ats.jta.common.jtaPropertyManager.getJTAEnvironmentBean(jtaPropertyManager.java:42)
        at com.arjuna.ats.jta.TransactionManager.transactionManager(TransactionManager.java:72)
        ... 23 more Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: missing property file arjuna-properties.xml
        at com.arjuna.common.util.propertyservice.PropertiesFactory.getPropertiesFromFile(PropertiesFactory.java:93)
        at com.arjuna.common.util.propertyservice.PropertiesFactory.initDefaultProperties(PropertiesFactory.java:236)
        at com.arjuna.common.util.propertyservice.PropertiesFactory.getDefaultProperties(PropertiesFactory.java:66)
        at com.arjuna.common.internal.util.propertyservice.BeanPopulator.getNamedInstance(BeanPopulator.java:77)
        ... 26 more
```

my dependencies are

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- JBoss Transactions dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.jbossts</groupId>
        <artifactId>jbossjta</artifactId>
        <version>4.16.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.ogm</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-ogm-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0.CR1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.ogm</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-ogm-infinispan</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0.Alpha1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: as per the JPA spec, where is your JTA datasource?

Comment: I hv no other resources. what is the JTA datasource

Comment: Read the JPA spec, the persistence.xml should have jta-data-source when using JTA transactions. If on the other hand you chose Resource Local transactions then you can do what you have there.

Comment: do I hv to make some changes to use Resource Local mode?

Comment: Read the JPA spec? If you have "transaction-type="JTA"" then you have to have jta-data-source, so change that transaction-type!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some problems with the configuration and I'm not sure if it's related to your issue.

1. You set `hibernate.ogm.datastore.provider` to `infinispan` but  then
   you set `hibernate.ogm.mongodb.database`. Are you trying to work 
   with Infinispan or MongoDB?
2. You are using an old dependency, you should try Hibernate OGM 5.0.4.Final
3. All the properties you set with hibernate.ogm.**mondogb**.* are wrong, you should use hibernate.ogm.**datastore**.*. [Check the documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/ogm/reference/en-US/html_single/) for the specific properties for the db you are using
4. You can also try to replace jbossjta dependency with:

   org.jboss.narayana.jta
     narayana-jta
     5.4.0.Final

You don't need a datasource because you are not dealing with Relational Databases. Hibernate OGM take the information from the configuration and its own dialects.

Let me know if the problem persists.

EDIT: Added point 4